# Startapp not showing ads

Tags: ads

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "........", "206198791", true);
    
    startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
    startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad
```

For the first time when i implement my startapp ads in my app its display ads and work properly and when i run my app again its not showing any ads without any change in my code.
startapp version 2.4.1

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack-overflow but the question you asked is in wrong way. The title should be self explanatory and the description should be the what problem you are facing or what error you are getting so that  others can understand and answer to your question so, I would suggest edit your question share more details.